# Use ng-bind-html-unsafe with expression containing brackets

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-directive, ng-bind-html, ng-bind

For angular to render an expression in a template that has a hyphen for the property name a brackets must be used instead of a dot. Example docs["paragraph-content"] instead of docs.paragraph-content. I am trying to print this variable inside ng-bind-html-unsafe like ng-bind-html-unsafe="doc["paragraph-content"]" inside my directive template but I am getting a syntax error , Error: Syntax Error: Token 'undefined' not a primary expression at column NaN of the expression [doc[] starting at [doc[].

```
      template: '<div>' +
            '<input ng-model="query" placeholder="Check your face" name="Search"></input>' +
            '<h2 id="search-list-title" class="list-header-title">Search Results for {{query}}</h2>' +
            '<form id="search-list-form" class="list-row list-form" ng-repeat="doc in results.docs">' +
            '  <a  id="search-item-title" class="list-element list-title" href="retrieve-graph?id={{doc.id}}"><p>{{doc["paragraph-subject"]}}</p></a>'  +
            ' <p id="search-item-content" class= "list-element list-content" ng-bind-html-unsafe="doc["paragraph-content"]"></p>'  +
            '  <p id="search-item-id" class= "list-email list-element">{{doc["user-email"]}}</p>'  +
            '  <!--<p>{{doc.title}}</p>-->'  +
            '  <!--urls point to user paragraph list and goes to specific paragraph through anchor link'  +
            ' <!--Need to create form that inserts id as parameter so can query and display on template page <p><a target="_blank" href="{{doc.id}}"> {{doc.url}}</a></p>-->' +
            ' <br>'+
            '</form>'+
            '</div>'
            ,
```

Comment: you need to escape your apostrophes, so try `"doc[\'paragraph-content\']"`

Comment: cheked again and did not work ended up doing , $scope.onesubject = "paragraph-subject"; then doing ng-bind-html-unsafe="doc[onesubject]" , thanks